# Type '(email: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(email: IEmail)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

anyone has an idea what causes the ff issue and how do we address this one . property) closeEmail: (email: IEmail) => string

Ideas would be much appreciated

I was tracing the type EmailSelection but the issue indicates on that part ...

[image]

#Code - EmailSelection.tsx

```
type EmailSelection = {
          isEmailOpen: boolean;
          closeEmail: (email: IEmail) => string;
        };
        type IEmail = {
          emailAddress: string;
          firstName: string;
          id: number;
          lastName: string;
        };
        const EmailSelection: FC<EmailSelection> = ({ isEmailOpen, closeEmail }) => {
          const { isPending, isError, isSuccess, data } = useAppSelector(
            (state) => state.yardUser
          );
        
          const emailList = data ? data.data : [];
        
          return (
            <Dialog
              open={isEmailOpen}
              keepMounted
              onClose={closeEmail}
              aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            >
              <DialogTitle>Select Email</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <List
                  style={{
                    maxHeight: "500px",
                    overflow: "auto",
                  }}
                  disablePadding
                >
                  {emailList.map((email: IEmail) => (
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                      <ListItemButton onClick={() => closeEmail(email)}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                          <EmailIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={email.emailAddress} />
                      </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
          );
        };
```

#main dialog that uses the EmailSelection

#snippet

```
 const closeEmail = (email: string) => {
    setOpenEmail(false);
  }
```

#snippet

```
  return (
        <Dialog
          maxWidth={maxWidth}
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Edit Assignment</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }} style={{ padding: 20 }}>
              <div>
                <EmailSelection closeEmail={closeEmail} isEmailOpen={isEmailOpen} />
```

#snippet ts

```
    type EmailSelection = {
  isEmailOpen: boolean;
  closeEmail: (email: IEmail) => string;
};
type IEmail = {
  emailAddress: string;
  firstName: string;
  id: number;
  lastName: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to return anything from that function

```
type EmailSelection = {
  isEmailOpen: boolean;
  closeEmail: (email: IEmail) => void;
};
```

or actually return a string

```
const closeEmail = (email: string) => {
  setOpenEmail(false);
  return 'a string for some reason'
}
```

Comment: do you mean on type EmailSelection = { ?

Comment: I did both of your answer sir but it is still the same issue

Comment: You should choose one

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QOK6Ctz still the same issue Sir

Comment: what I did is I returned a string

Comment: Your type expects parameter of type `IEmail`, but your actual function requires `string`, but you don't use that parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the closeEmail function like this:

```
const closeEmail = (email: {
  emailAddress: string;
  firstName: string;
  id: number;
  lastName: string;
}) => {
    setOpenEmail(false);
    return '';
}
```

Comment: After testing, please let me know your feedback.